# CMake Error while building project

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build a open source project .
https://github.com/atefm/Android-Object-Detection.

Spends a lots of time but I can not make it build. Each time I a get Cmake error. I have read some StackOverflow answers but they did not help or maybe I did not understand what exactly should I do. I am very new to JNI so I do not have much idea about native build process. Please help me below is the error I am getting. Please comment for if you need more details.

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing '/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake' with arguments {-H/home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app -B/home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=21 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fexceptions}
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
Open File
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Build command failed.
Error while executing '/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake' with arguments {-H/home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app -B/home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/rudra/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=21 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fexceptions}
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
Open File
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

Comment: clean the build directory, make sure you have the right version of cmake required by the project and try again.

Comment: On cleaning the project i am getting `Cause: executing external native build for cmake /home/rudra/Downloads/Projects/CVTEST/Android-Object-Detection-master/app/CMakeLists.txt`. You can check  `CMakeLists.txt` in the link if needed.

Comment: cmake is installed . Can you please try to build the project. I have no idea of JNI. should i have to make some chnages in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: From what I see in the question post, the error has nothing common with JNI - it is about CMake cannot find/detect C and C++ compilers. Show **how exactly** you perform the building of the package.

Comment: As @Tsyvarev says, you may not have compilers installed. make sure you do.